# Simple ReactJs Example not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting issue with simple ReactJs Example using from react website :

First i imported :

```
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
```

Then i copy and pasted code :

```
// tutorial1.js
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<CommentBox/>, document.body);
```

When opened page nothing show. Also tried :

```
document.getElementById('example')
```

No error in console don't no what issue is.

I am using jquery in page and using Laravel with Blade templates let me know if that is issue.

Also tried to use external script :

```
<script src="/lib/react-example.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
```

This is my [Live Server](http://crowdfunds.in) you can check here.

Thanks

Comment: Try wrap `ReactDOM.render` with Immediately-Invoked Function eg. `$(function() {ReactDOM.render(<CommentBox/>, document.body);})`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to use the JSX syntax, you need to mark your script tags with `type=text/babel` and also [load the babel browser script](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) with:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<CommentBox/>, document.body);
</script>
```

Here is an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnfwgxa2/1/), unfortunately it doesn't work on StackOverflow snippets.

Another option is to transcompile your `.jsx` it to javascript on the server side using a solution such as [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/).

Comment: Thanks it's working but why need to use browser.min.js ? can't use JSX as previous version ? is browser.min.js library like jquery ?

Comment: Even babel seems to [no longer actively maintain](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/)  support for compilation in browser. I assume you previously used the `JSXTransformer.js` library, however it has also been marked as [deprecated and no longer bundled](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html) with React.

Comment: There is also a [more detailed blog post](http://www.phpied.com/from-jsxtransformer-to-babel/) describing the transition to babel.

Comment: Spent more than hour trying to figure this out. Thank you!