# React JS min Script Link not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, babeljs, unpkg

Using IntelliJ Idea and Created an index.htm file

I am just trying to include the below links and run the code on server end
Nothing is getting rendered on the screen :

```
<html >
<head>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <title>Live Link</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="Output"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello Human</h1>, window.document.getElementById('Output'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This older versions link work, but new version links are not working.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33963992/5078763

> Getting below Error in Console.log:

```
    babel.min.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: Range out of order in character class
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (babel.min.js:5)
    at t (babel.min.js:1)
    at Object.t.__esModule (babel.min.js:19)
    at t (babel.min.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (babel.min.js:2)
    at t (babel.min.js:1)
    at Object.e.exports (babel.min.js:1)
    at t (babel.min.js:1)
    at Object.e.exports.version (babel.min.js:1)
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:5
t @ babel.min.js:1
t.__esModule @ babel.min.js:19
t @ babel.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:2
t @ babel.min.js:1
e.exports @ babel.min.js:1
t @ babel.min.js:1
e.exports.version @ babel.min.js:1
t @ babel.min.js:1
t.__esModule @ babel.min.js:16
t @ babel.min.js:1
t.__esModule @ babel.min.js:11
t @ babel.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:2
t.__esModule @ babel.min.js:2
t @ babel.min.js:1
t.__esModule @ babel.min.js:10
t @ babel.min.js:1
t.__esModule @ babel.min.js:14
t @ babel.min.js:1
t.__esModule @ babel.min.js:1
t @ babel.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:1
raven.min.js:2 <img>​
```

Comment: `Nothing is getting rendered on the screen` - I see **Hello Human** - have you done debugging 101 - checked the browsers developer tools console for errors

Comment: I have added the Error Log I got

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minified `babel.min.js` contains utf-8 encoded strings. You can make your example work by putting a `<meta charset="utf-8">` inside your `<head>`.